# Best way to use match..with to conditionally insert values into a sequence expression?

Tags: f#

I thought maybe `match .. with` might work like `if` inside a sequence expression:

```
let foo (m: 'a option) =
    [ yield 'a'
      match m with
        | Some _ -> yield 'b'
      yield 'c' ]
```

That is, I only need to specify the matching case(s) while the fail case is treated as a no-op. Unfortunately this is not the case, a non-match raises an exception.

I found that I can still get the desired result if I use `yield!` like this:

```
let bar (m: 'a option) =
    [ yield 'a'
      match m with
        | Some _ -> yield 'b'
        | _ -> yield! []
      yield 'c' ]
```

This works but is it the best way? Just wondering if there is any more standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funk's answer is correct, but you can also replace `yield! []` with a simple `()`:

```
let bar (m: 'a option) =
    [ yield 'a'
      match m with
        | Some _ -> yield 'b'
        | _ -> ()
      yield 'c' ]
```

The rules inside computation expressions are that any expression that evaluates to the `unit` type (that is, the `()` value) will be replaced by that expression's "zero" value (whatever "zero" means for that type of thing). For a list, the "zero" value is the empty list. This is *also* what is happening behind the scenes when you have an `if` statement without an `else` clause: the `else` clause is implicitly `else ()`. And so Funk's answer is equivalent to `if Option.isSome m then yield 'b' else ()`, which in a list expression is equivalent to `if Option.isSome m then yield 'b' else yield! []`.

Hopefully that explanation is clear rather than confusing you further; computation expressions always take a bit of brain-bending before they "click" and you get it. If you need more explanation, let me know.

Comment: Not confusing at all, your explanation is excellent. Learning that returning () in a sequence expression is equivalent to 'yield!'ing the "zero" for that type of sequence is really good to know and is clearly the better way to do it.

Comment: Be careful, BTW, not to confuse `()` with `return ()` -- the two are **not** the same (the fact that you used the term "returning ()" in your answer made me wonder if you thought they were). I can't explain it fully in a comment (and there are parts I'd probably get wrong since I don't 100% grok every detail yet), but read https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/computation-expressions.html for the best explanation of F#'s computation expressions that I know of, anywhere on the Internet.

Comment: Ah badly worded on my part, I did indeed understand it as just (). That looks like a fantastic resource btw, given the somewhat magical (to me) nature of F#'s computation expressions, I'll work through it when I get a chance.